# Lotus Notes X-Frame option

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a Lotus Notes web application which is been loaded in to another web application, after we upgraded to domino from 9.0.1 to Domino V10.0.4 the application fails to load in this portal, the application can be accessed individually in browser but while loading in another application it fails with error

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://achme.com/achme.NSF/frameset?readform does not permit cross-origin framing.

any hint on fixing the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZsbB.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your Domino- server has a header value for X-Frame-Options set.

This can either be done with a Website- Rule of type "HTTP response headers" that defines the header in the domino directory:

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Possible values:

> X-Frame-Options: deny
>   X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
>   X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example.com/

Or it is set via notes.ini Entry:

HTTPAdditionalRespHeader=X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Check your domino directory and the notes.ini for the setting and set it to something more relaxed if you need the page to be loaded in an iframe.

Do you happen to have changed the FQDN of your Domino server when upgrading? That might be a reason why the same setting worked in Domino 9 (old hostname) and does not work for the new server (new hostname).

Comment: FQDN has not been changed, I am adding the website rules will let you know the results

Comment: by commenting the parameter in notes.ini it worked.. I assume on upgrade it added this parameter X-Frame-Options: sameorigin